# Website errors out when connecting to page that accesses database

Tags: asp.net, database

Just to make it easy, say I have a really simple web site created in Visual Studio (C#) that accesses 1 database created in SQL Server Management Studio.  There is one DropDown Menu that is populated from a SqlDataSource control.  The Connection String for that data source is just my local PC as the server name (so pcname\SQLEXPRESS):

`Data Source=pcname\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Hardware;Integrated Security=True`

When I test the site it works fine (F5), but when I publish it using Web Deploy via GoDaddy and access the site, it error out on the page that accesses the database.  I'm assuming this is because the site is only set up to access the database locally.  I sort of thought that if I just uploaded the .mdf file to my site's File Manager that it would work but obviously I'm wrong.  What huge thing am I missing?  Thanks.

Comment: You need to setup your db on godaddy. Just google `"godaddy sql server"`, there are ample tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I just wanted to come back and state exactly how I ended up making this work in case anyone else comes looking.  Again to reiterate, I'm using Visual Studio 2015 to create a website using c#.  I have a MS SQL database connecting to my local SQL Express server via SQL Server Management Studio.  I purchased a domain and hosting through GoDaddy; this is how you get your local database to work once the site is published ([I used this post as a guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171124/local-sql-server-database-to-godaddy-sql-server)).

1) Go into Management Studio, right-click your Database and click Tasks>Generate Scripts.

2) Click through the screens and save the script to a New Query Window.

3) Go into your GoDaddy account, click Manage next to your Web Hosting option, click Add Database, and then fill in the relevant information.  Just as an example for the further steps, say we call our database DB123, username is Aeternus, password is Password123, and server IP is 111.222.333.444

4) After it's created, make note of your Database Server IP address and click Webadmin at the end of the row for your newly created database.

5) Now that you're in the MyLittleAdmin application, click Tools on the left side and click New Query.  Now, paste in all the contents of the query window you've had created in Management Studio and click submit.  It will create all the tables (You can go to Databases>User Databases>Database Name>Tables to confirm.

6) Go back to Management Studio, right-click your database and click Tasks>Export Data. The "Choose a Data Source" screen should just be all the defaults you normally use.  On the next "Choose a Destination" screen, Server name is the server IP address you're remembering from before, change the radio button to "Use SQL Server Authentication" and fill in the username and password you created.  Then in "Database:", select your database.  From there, finish the wizard and it will send your data over.  If you go back to MyLittleAdmin, click on one of your tables and then click "Open Table" (little icon right below the database icon) you can confirm your tables have been populated.

7) Finally, you need to update your Visual Studio connection strings.  Open your web.config file, you should see something like

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=MyPCName\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Hardware;Integrated Security=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Using the information above, your connection string is now

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Server=111.222.333.444; Database=DB123; User ID=Aeternus; Password=Password123; Trusted_Connection=False"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And that should be it, well, it worked for me at least!

Answer (score 0):

You're using a connection string that connects to your local SqlExpress.   **Why not writing a connection string for using MSSQL of Godaddy?** Check this to see if it can help you. 
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24571059/How-attach-SQL-Express-db-to-SQL-Server-GoDaddy-Hosting.html

If you do want to access SqlExpress remotely, check this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2005/05/05/how-to-configure-express-to-accept-remote-connections/

Comment: Please add some substance to your answer: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: @Larry Xia Yeah the first couple steps are helpful, I just have no idea where to find the connection string, I might have to talk to their support because all the articles I found for finding the string on your GoDaddy account seem to be outdated.

Comment: @Aeternus Have a look at this [link](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/11/write-connection-strings-in-webconfig.html), this one looks simple to understand how to write a connection string. Try to get the necessary information on godaddy to make it work.  Good luck budddy!